# How do I edit this Galauness Blogger XML template?

Tags: xml, templates, customization, blogger

I'm in the midst of revamping my book blog and am currently trying to customise the Galauness Blogger XML template by Iksandi Lojaya. I'm stuck and could really use some help, though!

Here is the template code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4ur1im3n18dnb9/Galauness.xml

This is the demo:
http://galauness-demo.blogspot.com/

However, what I'm stuck on is that I don't know how to edit the code so that my posts won't be displayed with picture grid layout on the homepage. I want to edit it so that it'll look more like the homepage of Kari Mew's website:

http://  www .karimew. com/ (please delete the spaces in between.)

I have tried asking the template designer for help, but he hasn't replied my question for a long time.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't support questions asking us to go elsewhere to debug a problem that will then no longer exist once you fix it. There needs to be sufficient information in your question here to make it have value for future readers; this is a reference site, not a "personal website issue debugging" site. You'll need to [edit] your question and put the *relevant* parts of any code here, and make it clear what the issue is *here* (whether it be in text or with an image).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of `function snips_image_creator()`. Its the function which creates thumbnails for blog posts.

Try commenting/removing following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.write(snips_image_creator(&quot;<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>&quot;,&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;));
</script>
```